# Google distancematrixservice response.rows[i].elements.status is zero_results but variable undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the example code from Google API for distance matrix Service. I want to catch the ZERO_RESULTS return, but if I'm trying to check response.rows[i].elements.status, but the console.log() says it's undefined.

If I dump response.rows[i].elements to console I see the value set to "ZERO_RESULTS".

```
function calcDistance() {
  var finalDistance = "";
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix(
     {
        origins: [autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location],
        destinations: [autocomplete2.getPlace().geometry.location],
        travelMode: 'DRIVING'
      }, callback);

   function callback(response, status) {

      if (status == 'OK') {
          var origins = response.originAddresses;
          var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;    

          for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
            var results = response.rows[i].elements;

            console.log(response.rows[i].elements);
            console.log(response.rows[i].elements.status);

            for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                var element = results[j];
                //alert('status' + results.status);
                var duration = element.duration.text;
                var from = origins[i];
                var to = destinations[j];
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

[Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z02d.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. `elements` is an array. `response.rows[i].elements.status` is undefined, `response.rows[i].elements[0].status` works.

**code snippet:**

```js
function calcDistance() {
  var finalDistance = "";
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins: ["New York, NY"],
    destinations: ["Newark, NJ"],
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  }, callback);

  function callback(response, status) {

    if (status == 'OK') {
      var origins = response.originAddresses;
      var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;

      for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
        var results = response.rows[i].elements;

        console.log(response.rows[i].elements);
        console.log(response.rows[i].elements[0].status);

        for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
          var element = results[j];
          var duration = element.duration.text;
          var from = origins[i];
          var to = destinations[j];
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function initialize() {
  calcDistance();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
```